# Ansible Playbook Syntax Issue - when: list

Tags: ansible

I am gathering facts on my localhost.

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_dns": {
            "nameservers": [
                "192.168.1.2", 
                "192.168.1.3"
            ], 
            "search": [
                "example.com", 
            ]
        }
    }, 
    "changed": false
}
```

I need to be able to access the nameservers: **192.168.1.2** and **192.168.1.3**

I have tried the following and still get an error in the syntax. I do not see any docs online that show me how to access nested values.

```
# Method 1
- name: Allow httpd access to files on CIFS volumes that are labeled with the cifs_t type
  seboolean: name=httpd_use_cifs state=true persistent=yes
  when: ansible_dns == nameservers == '192.168.1.2' and ansible_dns == nameservers == '192.168.1.3'

# Method 2
- name: Allow httpd access to files on CIFS volumes that are labeled with the cifs_t type
  seboolean: name=httpd_use_cifs state=true persistent=yes
  when: nameservers == '192.168.1.2' and nameservers == '192.168.1.3'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access nested elements with *dot*: `ansible_dns.nameservers`.

Not sure what condition you want to construct, but one of possible ways:
`when: "'192.168.1.2' in ansible_dns.nameservers and '192.168.1.3' in ansible_dns.nameservers"`

Comment: I actually used `ansible_dns.nameservers == '192.168.1.7'`. I'm sure your method would've worked too! When I was filtering `ansible local -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_dns.nameservers'` and the .(dot) did not work, I assumed it would not work in a Playbook.

Comment: EDIT: Just kidding. Your "in" statement works and mine does not :)